# VBA (Upper) Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a bit of VBA to switch an entire Excel worksheet to upper case.

However it trips over and gives a Type Mismatch error and fails half way through.

```
Sub MyUpperCase()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
        If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

[image]

I'm assuming it is tripping over a specific cell however there are hundreds of lines. Is there a way to get it to skip errors

Comment: Does `If Len(CStr(cell)) > 0 Then cell = UCase(CStr(cell))` help at all?

Comment: You've probably got a cell with an error in it - have you tried debugging your code to see what line is causing the error? Simply ignoring the error is bad practice.

Comment: Numerics might screw this up too. Basic error handling should solve for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert **all** cells to upper case text *(including formulas)*:

```
Sub MyUpperCase()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim cell As Range, v As String

        For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
            v = cell.Text
            If Len(v) > 0 Then cell.Value = UCase(v)
        Next cell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Be aware that all formulas not returning *Null* will also be converted to Text.

Comment: perfect, was falling over at the #N/A however the file doesn't have any formula's. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To see what cell (or cells) is the problem, you could try:

```
On Error Resume Next 'to enable in-line error-catching
    For Each cell In Range("$A$1:" & Range("$A$1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address)
        If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Debug.Print cell.Address
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next cell
On Error GoTo 0 'Turn off On Error Resume Next
```

`On Error Resume Next` is often abused, especially by new VBA programmers. Don't turn it on at the beginning of a sub and never turn it off and never check `Err.Number`. I find it a very good idea to think of it having a specific scope, and emphasizing that scope by indenting the statements in it, as I have done above. @MacroMan raises a good point that errors shouldn't be simply ignored (which is what happens if you abuse this construct).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following error trapping in the middle of your code:

```
On Error Resume Next
If Len(cell) > 0 Then cell = UCase(cell)

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " has an error !"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

**Note**: Your code is fine with Numeric values, it's the `#NA` and `#DIV/0` that's raising the errors when running your original code.